# Redirect to homepage after log in

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5

React newbie here. 
I have an application built with react and rails. There is a link to log-in, in the homepage. The takes the user to the log-in page. On verifying if the username exists, I am trying to redirect to the homepage using the below code.

```
export default class Login extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) { 
        super(props);
        this.state = {
             username: '', 
             isValid: false
        };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        axios.get('/isuser/'+this.state.username)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({ isValid: true });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({username: event.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isValid) {
             return <Redirect to={{
                      pathname: '/',
                      state: { 
                              username: this.state.username, 
                              loggedIn: true 
                      }
              }}/>
        }
        return (
                <div>
                //form
                </div>
        );
    }
}
```

However, the props is empty. I am fetching it using the code below.

```
export default class LoginLink extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        if(this.props.state == undefined) { // always empty
            this.state = {loggedIn: false, redirect: false};
        }
        else {
            this.state = {
                       loggedIn: this.props.location.state.loggedIn, 
                       username: this.props.location.state.username
            };
        }
        this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleOnClick(event) {
        this.setState({redirect: true});
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.redirect) {
            return <Redirect to={{
                      pathname: '/login'
                    }}/>
        }
        else {
            if (this.state.loggedIn) {
                return (
                    <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="topnav">
                        <li><a href="">{this.state.username}</a></li>
                    </ul>
                );
            }
            else {
                return (
                    <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="topnav">
                        <li>
                           <Button bsStyle="link" onClick={this.handleOnClick}>Log in</Button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my routes:

```
<main>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
    <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>
  </Switch>
</main>
```

I don't know if there is some sort of an infinite loop(calling super). 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: avoid mutating the state firstly , use `this.setState();` instead of `this.state() ` what is the component you want to `<Redirect>` to ?

Comment: @Aaqib you can do that okay in the constructor

Comment: @Archana is that the constructor for the Redirect component - It is unclear?

Comment: @mjwatts Sorry for not being very clear. I have updated the code. Yes that is in the constructor.

Comment: What is the error it's giving, although it's not to be written this way, it should work from what you posted. When is the unexpected happening? When you are trying to redirect to the homepage?

Comment: @NanduKalidindi I'm sorry. I am relatively new. Could you please point me to the right way of doing things if what I am doing is not advisable?  It doesn't give any errors. Props inside the login link constructor aren't being set. Yes this happens during homepage redirection.

Comment: You mean you are not able to access `this.props.username` and `this.props.loggedIn` in your `Home` component? You added `LoginLink` component, is that supposed to be the `Home` component?

Comment: Yes I am unable to access this.props.username and this.props.loggedIn. Yes LoginLink is the home component.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very good practice to return different states in the constructor. as It's unclear is the state structure of the component. I'd suggest something like:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    loggedIn: props.location.state.loggedIn || false,
    username: props.location.state.username || null,
  }
}
```

then in the `render()` function

```
render() {
  // if loggedIn go to '/'
  if (this.state.loggedIn) {
    return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { ...this.state, loggedIn: true } }} />
  }
  // otherwise
  // return something else or Redirect to login...
}
```

Comment: Hi IIan,
I have updated the code. Can you please take a look at it now?